# Work with Hilt with submodules of a feature module

Tags: dagger-hilt, android-module, android-architecture

Is there any way to make dagger hilt work with clean architecture that uses the presentation-domain-data as submodules?

For example I have `Feature A` as a module. This module has 3 submodules:

1. Presentation module
2. Domain module
3. Data module

How could I provide the needed dependencies for every submodule? **If I create a DI module (Another layer) then I'll need have them 3 submodules as a dependency and somehow I must return these dependencies** and I'm not able to do that because that creates a circular dependency (At least that's what I think)

- DI -> Domain -> DI
- DI -> Data -> DI
- DI -> Presentation -> DI

Also I'm breaking the rule "Domain should not depend on any module"